# "Smozzare" può significare "mangiarsi" alcuni suoni nel pronunciare le parole?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Ho visto un [video intitolato *Straniero, che ti piace dell'Italia?*](https://youtu.be/WKmbRaFNOv8) in cui l'umorista Enrico Brignano fa un monologo molto divertente sui turisti in Italia. In un certo momento, Brignano usa il verbo "smozzare": l'ho cercato su alcuni dizionari e ho visto che si tratta di un sinonimo di "mozzare", che può significare tagliare via, tranciare di netto, spesso con forza e persino con violenza. Ma non sono sicura di aver capito il significato di questo verbo nel contesto del video. Brignano si sta lamentando che i turisti non pronunciano bene le parole che usano per riferirsi alla cucina italiana: non pronunciano le due "t" di "spaghetti" (parlano invece di "spagheri") e dicono "piza" con una sola "z". E allora fa questa battuta: "Perché da me pretendi che io pronunci bene le tue parole e tu, da me, quando parli **smozzi**. Perché? Perché?" Dal contesto ho pensato che "smozzare" possa significare "mangiarsi" alcuni suoni nel pronunciare le parole. È così? Si tratta di qualcosa di inventata da Brignano o è un'espressione che si usa (magari in ambito regionale)?

Comment: Sì, significa tagliare, qui nel senso di interrompere le parole senza pronunciarle correttamente fino in fondo. ***Smozzare***: (non com.) mozzare, specialmente se in modo deciso, violento: http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=smozzare

Answer (score 1):

Sì,*"smozzare"* nel senso della frase significa proprio mangiarsi i suoni delle parole e mi sembra una contrazione (forse dialettale) di "smozzicare":

Secondo il dizionario italiano Olivetti (http://dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?parola=smozzicare)

> smozzicare:
>   spezzare in molte piccole parti; in senso figurato abbreviare, pronunciare malamente

Comment: Hai sentito usare “smozzare” in questo senso (oltre che da Brignano)? L'hai letto da qualche parte?

Comment: Mi è stato sufficiente leggere il brano riportato nella domanda per capire il senso della parola.

Comment: Ah, come qualunque altro madrelingua italiano: speravo che avessi un riferimento più oggettivo. Rimane aperta la questione se questa forma specifica sia un'invenzione di Brignano o usata correntemente da qualche parte.

Comment: No, mi dispiace :) potrebbe anche essere in effetti un'invenzione del comico.

Comment: Come suggerito nei dizionari l'uso non è comune, https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=smozzare&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csmozzare%3B%2Cc0 - la mia prima impressione era che si trattasse di un termine romanesco, o sopravvissuto nel dialetto romanesco.

Comment: Per curiosità, @Gio, il corposo *Dizionario romanesco* di Fernando Ravaro non lo riporta (mentre riporta “smozzicà”, tra l'altro col senso di “parlare a frasi brevi, a parole molto distaccate”).